# VIsualforce Page shows the website expired when I click a button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page that is call from a call center system Avaya, this system shows the visualforce page and when we click on button to save a record shows a error page with this message: " the website expired", someone has some workaround why this is happening?

This is the method that is call when we try to save the record:

```
public void updateMemberStatus(){
    if(campaignId != 'choose' && memberStatusId != 'choose' && activeContact != null){
        Savepoint sp;
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        }
        try{
            system.debug('#### try ' + campaignId + ' ' + activeContact + ' ' + country);
            Status_Telemarketing__c campaignMember = [SELECT id, name, N_mero_de_Llamadas__c, Status__c FROM Status_Telemarketing__c WHERE Campa_a__c=:campaignId AND Contacto__c=:activeContact.Id AND Contacto__r.Pa_s_Aldeas__c =: country];
            system.debug('#### ' + campaignMember);
            campaignMember.Status__c = memberStatusId;
            activeContact.CallCenter_en_Contacto__c = false;
            if(campaignMember.N_mero_de_Llamadas__c == null){
                campaignMember.N_mero_de_Llamadas__c = 1;
            }
            else{
                campaignMember.N_mero_de_Llamadas__c += 1;
            }
            memberStatusId = 'choose';
            system.debug('#### update cm');
            update campaignMember;
            system.debug('#### update c');
            update activeContact;
            if(memberStatusNextAction == 'next'){
                system.debug('#### grab');
                grabContact();
            }
            else{
                system.debug('#### campaign');
                chooseCampaign();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String error = 'Hubo un problema al intentar actualizar el estado';
            if(e.getMessage().contains('List has no rows for assignment to SObject')){
                error += ': No se encontro el Status Telemarketing de este contacto, por favor corriga el incidente.';
            }
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                Database.rollback(sp);
            }
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, error));
            System.debug('ERROR: Cannot update the MemberStatus - Catch the exception:'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else{
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No se puede actualizar el estado, faltan datos'));
        System.debug('ERROR: Cannot update the MemberStatus - Missing Data');
    }
}
```

Comment: We would probably need to see some code. This message generally indicates the the page was reloaded and a form submission previously occurred.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for you reply, I just updated the question with code of the method.

Comment: We would need to see the VF as well, please. Ah, tambien, es 'corrija',  con j, no con g. :D